# isReady() returns true in closed state - why?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, servlet-3.1

[`ServletOutputStream.isReady()` javadoc says the following](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html#isReady--):

> Returns:
>        true if a write to this ServletOutputStream will succeed, otherwise returns false.

In spite of that Jetty's `ServletOutputStream` implementation, `HttpOutput` seems to behave rather confusing in the case when the stream is in `CLOSED` state. It returns `true`:

```
case CLOSED:
    return true;
```

Source: [HttpOutput.java:1011](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpOutput.java#L1011).

Furthermore, all three `write` methods in `HttpOutput` throws `EofException` when it's `CLOSED`:

```
case CLOSED:
    throw new EofException("Closed");
```

So it seems that write can never succeed. What's the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: I agree. You have four blatant bugs there, and it is certainly total madness for write methods to throw `EOFException`. Report them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key Fact: *A close call implies a write operation.*

The CLOSED internal state indicates that *usage* of the stream/output is CLOSED to that dispatch (not that the stream itself is actually closed).

How did we get into this state? Something has triggered the `ServletOutputStream.close()` (and in turn `HttpOutput.close()`) and now no more writes are allowed on that stream from the current dispatch.

In the CLOSED state, a flush occurs.

- A flush will commit the response
- A flush will finish writing the various buffers present on the various layers of the exchange / connection / output.
- If there is an aggregate buffer (for many small writes) it writes that out.
- If there is a compression layer (gzip) it will force a flush from there as well.
- Then all of those buffers also go through the `Transfer-Encoding` layer (eg: chunked).
- Then the network write occurs.

The `HttpOutput` is also the one point of output for all nested requests, such as using `include()` from `RequestDispatcher` which will reopen the `HttpOutput` for use during the `include()` and then close it again.

Once the `HttpOutput` is fully and completely flushed/finished (no more dispatches, no more writes, etc), then the final buffer flush is done, transfer-encodings are completed, the HttpOutput is reset, recycled, and returned to the HttpConnection for use with the next exchange.

We could do a better job of javadoc'ing that in the codebase, or at least using constants and variable names that make more sense.

Opened https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2687

Regarding the Jetty `EofException` (not the JVM `EOFException`) on write.

Once the `ServletOutputStream` is CLOSED for usage on the specific dispatch, further calls to `write()` will result in a Jetty `EofException`.

There is also a flavor of `EofException` where your committed response details were violated.

Eg: you declared a response `Content-Length` of say 40MB, but wrote 41MB, you exceeded the capability of that committed response, this is an IOException. And the Servlet spec tells us to throw an `IOException` in this case.

Jetty will throw the Jetty internal `EofException` (which extends IOException) to indicate this specific scenario and abort the connection, breaking any connection persistence you may have wanted.

Comment: eh, not quiite. I meant "the one point", meaning that for complex requests that encompass multiple nested requests, there still only 1 HttpOutput instance managing it all.

Comment: You have to admit that `EofException` on write was a terrible choice. There is no end of file involved: just a state transition. It should have been something like a `ClosedException`.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: Thanks, that sentence was the key.